# asynch transfer fails in AWS/s3 while synch transfer works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to transfer a few files from an s3 bucket to my laptop. When I do the transfer synchronously, like this,  it works fine:
$manager = new \Aws\S3\Transfer($client, $source, $dest);
$manager->transfer();

But when i try to do the same transfer aynch like this:

```
    $manager = new \Aws\S3\Transfer($client, $source, $dest);
    $promise = $manager->promise();

    $promise->then(function () {
        echo 'Done!';
    });
    $promise->otherwise(function ($reason) {
        echo 'Transfer failed: ';

    });
```

In this asynch case, the files are never transferred. The async code above is directly from AWS php SDK documentation. Is there something that they forgot to mention in the docs?

Comment: what's running this code?  my guess is that the parent thread ends and exits before the promise is resolve and the child processes are halted, what happens if you tell the promise to wait at the end?

Comment: I have't tried a wait since that will make it a synch, which already works.